# UINavigationBar with image, and then a continuous image below it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I need to make a continuous image on my uiviewcontroller part of it being the navigation-bar (agenda-top.png) and the other part being the background for a uiview element directly under the navigation bar (agenda-bottom.png)

I can't make it work! iOS7 seems to add some kind of effect on the nav bar which I haven't been able to disable...

I tried: setting barStyle, tint color, statusBarStyle... and few others... it's always there. setting translucent property crashes my app.

I set the image like so:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"agenda-top.png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image  
 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

how can I accomplish this?

these are the images if it helps anyone, I can't upload them due to no rep on this account
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE3qj.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc1KB.png

Comment: Is other UIView a part of navigation bar?

Comment: Nope it's part of the content view below the navigation bar

Comment: can you show me how you are adding other uiview below navigation bar?

Comment: I do it in xib, it's a uiimageview with the bottom part, contained in a uiview which is the entire screen...

I'm not sure where you going with this, does the components below effect how the navbar looks?

essentially the bottom part looks spot on, it's the top that has a weird "lightning effect" / gradient or something.

just for tests sake I tried to instead of setting background image of navbar to make it solid black... it then becomes light purple.

Comment: Without looking at the nib, sorry I cannot help.